# Server connection lost after successful login with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, vaadin

After successful login using Spring security I will loose connection and my client is trying to reconnect. This is my config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery(
                        "select nickname,password, true from client where nickname=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                        "select username, role from user_roles where username=?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/*")
                .access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')");
        http.formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true);
    }

    @Bean
    public static NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

I am using vaadin flow. After successful login my base page will show but right after that it will loose connection and it will start reconnecting in an endless loop.

This is the header of my root page.

```
@Route(value = "")
public class BasePageView extends VerticalLayout
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this `http.csrf().disable()` to your `configure` method in `SecurityConfig`.

I do not know exactly why it is not working without that. If it is Vaadin Flow specific or not. Maybe someone else will help us to understand.

Comment: ah I missed that in my answer, well done ! as long as you do not provide the csrf token you're consider as a potential attacker https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF), It's not link with Vaadin especially but with every templating language. Actually, you should provide a valid csrf token on all pages to avoid this kind of attack, disabling it is not safe on a stateful context

Comment: @slemoine were you able to fix the problem? I am having the same problem when I use NTLM in spring boot and Vaadin flow. As you mention disabling it then suddenly everything works., but it is not a good thing to just disbale CSRF.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should override super class method

`protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception`

instead of `public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception`

For instance this sample works for me :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {    
 auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("test").roles("USER");
    }

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/*")
            .access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')");
    http.formLogin()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true);
}
}
```

alsoe double check that your role name is correct in your database, and I think you should set antMatchers to /** instead of /* to handle multi-level url

Comment: Unluckily it did not helped. It is still trying to reconnect. Can you think of something else which may cause this problem ?

Comment: Well unless your browser does not store any cookie... I don’t see why. Could you check if the server set a JSESSION cookie for your client ?